# Counting by earliest date found from an inner join?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, customerusermap and users. Whenever a user signs up with our product, they immediately get added into a table called users but it isn't until they start paying for a user that they get added to a table called customerusermap.

The users table looks like this:

```
id    | customer_id        | firstname | lastname | created_at
-------------------------------------------------------
1725  | cus_3hEmhErE2jbwsO | Abby      | Smith    | 2015-03-19
1726  | cus_7oNweUrE4jbwr2 | Sam       | Peters   | 2015-06-20
```

The customerusermap table looks like this:

```
customer_id        | user_id | created_at
------------------------------------------
cus_3hEmhErE2jbwsO | 9275    | 2015-09-01
cus_3hEmhErE2jbwsO | 2628    | 2015-09-05
cus_3hEmhErE2jbwsO | 2358    | 2015-07-05
cus_3hEmhErE2jbwsO | 3158    | 2015-08-05
cus_3hEmhErE2jbwsO | 2487    | 2015-08-05
cus_3hEmhErE2jbwsO | 6044    | 2015-08-05
cus_7oNweUrE4jbwr2 | 8094    | 2015-08-25
cus_7oNweUrE4jbwr2 | 2345    | 2015-09-02
```

In this example, Abby(cus_3hEmhErE2jbwsO) is paying for 6 users. She started paying for user 2358 2015-07-05 so she should be considered a paying customer 07-2015, not 03-2015. Sam is paying for 2 users and he started paying for user 8094 in 08-2015 so he is considered to be a paying customer for 08-2015, not 06-2015. I have a query that grabs and groups by the number of paying customers each month:

```
SELECT concat(extract(MONTH from u.created_at),'-',extract(year from u.created_at)) as "Month", 
COUNT(distinct u.email) as "Total AB Paying Customers"
FROM customerusermap AS cm, users AS u
WHERE cm.customer_id=u.customer_id AND cm.user_id <> u.id
GROUP BY 1,extract(month from u.created_at),extract(year from u.created_at)
ORDER BY extract(year from u.created_at),extract(month from u.created_at);
```

But this grabs and counts by the date the customer was added to the users table, not the date they actually started paying. How would I grab the counts so that it grabs for the earliest date in the customerusermap table? What the needed output should look like in this example is:

```
Month    | Total AB Paying Customers
-------------------------------------
07-2015  | 1
08-2015  | 1
```

Comment: Can you provide needed output ?

Comment: hey, please see edited question!

Comment: @AshleyI. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM startedPayingDate), '-', 
              EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startedPayingDate)) AS "Month", 
       COUNT(*) AS "Total AB Paying Customers"
FROM (       
   SELECT customer_id, MIN(created_at) AS startedPayingDate 
   FROM customerusermap AS cm
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM users AS u
                     WHERE cm.user_id = u.id)
   GROUP BY customer_id ) AS t
GROUP BY 1
```

I used a `NOT EXISTS` operator to exclude records that relate to 'paying for themselves' customers (if that is really your intention).

Once you get the `MIN(created_at)` date per `customer_id`, then you can easily count per date in an outer query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f3cac/5)

Comment: Thanks so much! I just tweeked the query a bit (ie instead of the WHERE NOT EXISTS (....) stuff I put WHERE cm.customer_id = u.customer_id AND cm.user_id<>u.id